# posting a dynamic list of objects from a view to a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor

I am writing a page that allows users to enter results from test pits over a period of three days.
there is a min of two test pits and a max of ten test pits.

I initially put two pits in the View and provide add and remove buttons to allow users to add more pits.
It looks like this:
[image]
I use this javascript to add more pits:

```
        var maxPits = 10;
    var minPits = 2;
    var wrapper = $(".pits");
    var addButton = $(".addPit");
    var delButton = $(".delPit");
    var x = 2;
    $(addButton).click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (x < maxPits) {
            x++;
            $(wrapper).append('<div class="row pit' + x + '"><div class="col-sm-1">Pit ' + x + '</div><div class="col-sm-3"><input type="number" placeholder="1.234" name="pit' + x + 'day1" id="pit' + x + 'day1"></div><div class="col-sm-3"><input type="number" placeholder="1.234" name="pit' + x + 'day2" id="pit' + x + 'day2"></div><div class="col-sm-3"><input type="number" placeholder="1.234" name="pit' + x + 'day3" id="pit' + x + 'day3"></div></div>');
            updatePitCount();
        } else {
            alert('too many pits!');
        }
    });

    $(delButton).click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (x > minPits) {
            var lastPit = '.pit' + x;
            $("div").remove(lastPit);
            x--;
            updatePitCount();
        } else {
            alert('must have a minimum of two!');
        }
    });
```

My model looks like this:

```
    public class ResultsModel
{
    public List<Pit> Pits { get; set; }
}

public class Pit
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double Day1 { get; set; }
    public double Day2 { get; set; }
    public double Day3 { get; set; }
    public double Mean
    {
        get
        {
            var x = 0;
            var total = 0.0;

            if (Day1 > 0.0) { x += 1; total += Day1; }
            if (Day2 > 0.0) { x += 1; total += Day2; }
            if (Day3 > 0.0) { x += 1; total += Day3; }

            if(x>0) return (total) / x;
            return 0.0;
        }
    }
}
```

My partial view looks like this:

```
    <div class="container pits">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-1 btn-group">
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-plus addPit"></button>
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-minus delPit"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            TEST 1
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            TEST 2
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            TEST 3
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            Pit 1
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="number" placeholder="1.234" name="pit1day1" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="number" placeholder="1.234" name="pit1day2" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="number" placeholder="1.234" name="pit1day3" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            Pit 2
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="number" placeholder="1.234" name="pit2day1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="number" placeholder="1.234" name="pit2day2">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="number" placeholder="1.234" name="pit2day3">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The html is in a form that posts to a controller and I want the results from the tests to be available in the controller so that I can do some calculations on them. I am struggling to get the data from the page into the model

I want to something like this in the controller:

```
            foreach (var pit in model.Pits)
        {
            var x1 = pit.Day1;
            var x2 = pit.Day2;
            var x3 = pit.Day3;
            var m = pit.Mean;
            //do something...
        }
```

How do I get the dynamic data from the view into the controller via the model?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Razor used a spatial format of name attribute when you pass the value form view to action.

Example :

If you passing

```
public class ResultsModel
{
    public List<Pit> Pits { get; set; }
}
```

model into the view and receive the same then your name attribute format must like `Pits[0].Day1`.

so your html like

```
<input type="number" placeholder="1.234" name="Pits[0].Day1" />
<input type="number" placeholder="1.234" name="Pits[1].Day1" />
```

so one.

And one more thing use `for` loop rather than `foreach` if you use razor for generating the list of items.

If you passing

```
List<Pit>
```

into the view and receive the same then your name attribute format must like `[0].Day1`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. I changed the code as you suggested so my controller code became:
`for (int i = 0; i < model.Pits.Count; i++)
            {
                var x1 = model.Pits[i].Day1;
                var x2 = model.Pits[i].Day2;
                var x3 = model.Pits[i].Day3;
                var m = model.Pits[i].Mean;
                //do something...
            }`
 I also changed the html as you suggested and all the values are now passed to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You must post data to action via a form tag!

```
<form method="post" action="/Pit/Create">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1">
        Pit 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input type="number" placeholder="1.234" name="[0].Day1" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input type="number" placeholder="1.234" name="[0].Day2" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input type="number" placeholder="1.234" name="[0].Day3" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1">
        Pit 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input type="number" placeholder="1.234" name="[1].Day1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input type="number" placeholder="1.234" name="[1].Day2">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input type="number" placeholder="1.234" name="[1].Day3">
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi. This is a partial view, the form is specified in the main view page

Comment: Hi.ok.You don't need form tag.you only need to correct naming for bind in the controller.